# How to resize button after resizing pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a menu (main_menu), that has a Button and I want this button to stay in the middle after I resize the window. The program does draw a new button in the middle of the window but the old button is still visible and I cant figure out why. I tried to fill the screen with the background color again and then draw a new button, but the old one was still visible... Any Ideas ?

[image]
[image]

```
WINDOW_W , WINDOW_H =  1200, 800
SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((WINDOW_W,WINDOW_H),pg.RESIZABLE)
main_menu = Main_Menu(SCREEN)
main_menu.render()

while True:
    pg.event.pump()
    event = pg.event.wait()

    if event.type == pg.VIDEORESIZE:    
        new_w, new_h = event.dict['size']   
        SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((new_w, new_h), pg.RESIZABLE)        
        main_menu = Main_Menu(SCREEN)
        main_menu.render()


class Main_Menu:

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        screen_width, screen_height = screen.get_size()
        play_button = Button((255,0,0), screen_width/2 - 100, screen_height/2 - 25, 200, 50, "Test")
        self.button = play_button

    def render(self):

        self.button.draw(self.screen, 1) 
        pg.display.update()




class Button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self,win,outline=None):
        #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
            
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
        
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
```

Comment: I tried to fill the screen with a color and then draw a new button in the middle but as I said, the old one is still visible :/

Comment: yes but it also does not work

Comment: This is not the original code or at least it is not all the code. There is `self.screen` in the constructor of `Main_Menu`, but `self.display` in `Main_Menu.render`. You hide some information. I don't want to help you any more. You're alone.

Comment: The issue is still not reproducible. Hence, the bug is hidden in the "other 2k Lines".

Comment: Okay then I searched for the bug in the wrong place... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to save the original ratio between the size of the button and the size of the screen.
After that you want to check in a loop wether the screen size changed.
If so, change the size of the button back to the same ratio.

And same with the position of the button, just make sure that the ratio is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example drawing an image that stays in the centre of the window as the window is resized:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
image = pygame.Surface((120, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
image.fill(pygame.color.Color("royalblue"))
center_pos = (width // 2, height // 2)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.dict["size"]
            # recreate screen object required for pygame version 1
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            # TODO: resize image if needed
            center_pos = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center=center_pos))
    pygame.display.update()
```

If you're using the development release of pygame 2 then you won't need to recreate `screen` by calling `pygame.display.set_mode(…)`.